# custom node class with java's linkedlist class

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Been a while since I used java. I want to use Java's built in linkedlist class but I want a custom node class that has children and siblings. How can I write a custom node class that Java's linked list will use? Just a matter of creating the node class and declaring a linkedlist class but just create a new constructor that will override javas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList` uses a private `Node<E>` class internally. If this is just an academic exercise, given that the source code [is available](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l957) you could just start with that and go from there.